# Htaccess force https except on one url doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, zend-framework

I try to force all my website to https. So I did:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =""
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
```

It works. The problem is that I want that http calls on mywebsite.com/api/... work too. So I add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api(/.*)?`.

My .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =""
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api(/.*)?
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
```

But it doesn't work. If I call http://mywebsite.com/api/xxx it redirects me to https://mywebsite.com/index.php ..

I don't know why. Do you have any ideas?
I use Zend 1

---- EDIT ----

Changed my .htaccess to this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api(/.*)?
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php

Options +Indexes
IndexIgnore *
```

But still doesn't work

---- EDIT 2 ----

The new .htaccess (**this one is working**):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =""
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^/api
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

I had to add condition with `QUERY_STRING` and change last redirect to `index.php`

Thank you @MrWhite

Comment: Are you behind a proxy server?

Comment: @MrWhite nop, not behind a proxy

Answer (score 4):

You have the directives in the wrong order. Your canonical HTTP to HTTPS redirect should come before your internal rewrite (ie. your front controller). Otherwise, a request for `/api/<something>` is going to be internally rewritten to `/index.php` (since I assume `/api/<something>` doesn't exist as a real file). `/index.php` then won't match against your `RewriteCond` directive that is checking for `/api/<something>`. So you then get *redirected* to `https://example.com/index.php` (although you've given `http` in your example?).

> not behind a proxy

If you're not behind a proxy server then you should remove the conditions that check the `X-Forwarded-Proto` HTTP request header (these are only set by a proxy server, and if you aren't behind a proxy server then the client could maliciously set this header and avoid your redirect).

These two lines:

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http [OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =""
> ```

---

**UPDATE:** If you get a redirect loop after removing the above conditions then it might be that you are behind an SSL proxy after all (you should be able to tell by examining the HTTP request headers your application sees - you don't necessarily need access to the server config - in fact, you may not be able to tell by looking at the server config).

(When you are behind an SSL proxy then `HTTPS` is always `off` - your application serves an HTTP response to the SSL proxy that then serves an encrypted HTTPS response back to the client.)

Try the following:

```
Options +Indexes
IndexIgnore *

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# HTTP to HTTPS, except for the api subdirectory
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =""
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule !^api https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]

# Front controller
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Note that this doesn't canonicalise the www vs non-www.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to change order, and redirect HTTP to HTTPS before, but the problem is still here.

Comment: Make sure you've cleared your browser cache. The redirect you are seeing strongly suggests the directives are the other way round.

Comment: Edited my .htaccess to `RewriteCond %{HTTP} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api(/.*)?
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]`, and changed order but it still doesn't work (edited my question)

Comment: Why did you change `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on` to `RewriteCond %{HTTP} =on`? There is no server variable called `HTTP`. And it should be `!=on` (or `off`) since you are testing whether `HTTPS` is not "on" (or is "off"). If you used `RewriteCond %{HTTP} =on` then it will _never_ redirect - is that what you mean by "doesn't work" in your edited question?

Comment: Ah, in that case it sounds like you _are_ behind a proxy?! (eg. Cloudflare flexible SSL by chance?)

Comment: I can't access the server configuration .. So i don't know

Comment: Thank again @MrWhite. I tried your solution, but still not works. I posted what worked for me :)

Comment: Changing the last rewrite to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [NC,L,QSA]` changes the way your URLs are routed (they are now routed via the query string, not the request URI) - which also (potentially) requires a change to your application. Only if you do this do you need to check the `QUERY_STRING` server variable - otherwise the code is essentially the same.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of your code ,put only the following code at your main directory `.htaccess` file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+api/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

This will force all request except `api/` to be `https`  then if you request yourwebsite/api with `http` , `http`,`www`or without `www` it will go to `api/` directory because it is not `api/` issue to come with or without `https` as well as `www` and the above rule will be applied for none `https` because of this condition `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on` so if comes with this it will override thi rule and that why `http://yourwebsite/api` and `https://yourwebsite/api` will work

Comment: However, it seems the OP is probably behind an SSL proxy (hence the need to check `HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto` rather than `HTTPS`). When the OP tried something similar, they got a redirect loop (see the comments on the other answer).

Comment: Finally ,you are right , but when you asked him first , he said No